# Is lumen space of a thylakoid completely separate from the intermembrane chloroplast space?

Tags: chloroplasts

The question I have is whether thylakoids form actually completely independent "vacuoles" (i.e. independent membrane enclosed spaces) or whether the lumen space is connected to the intermembrane space of the chloroplast. I have this question because electron photographs that show slices can be sometimes misleading and connected structures may appear to look independent on photographs of slices.

Comment: This is an excellent question because in all textbook-diagram (yet I've seen) of mature chloroplasts, all the stroma-thylakoids and grana-thylakoids are drawn as detached-from the periplastidial space, but no-where I've read any text-mention of it.

Comment: I've also thought at earlier-classes, why chloroplast is not being called a "3-membrane bound" organelle.

Comment: Maybe a detachment-step take place in plastid-development, otherwise the compartmentalization would be poor, and the proton-gradient and other-sorts of chemical-difference would become weak